# Replacing // comments with /* comments */ in PHP

Tags: php, regex, code-generation

I'm creating a CSS generator in PHP which uses CSSX (yep, they are my idea) files (with a special syntax). One feature is 'short comments':

```
body
{
    font-family: Georgia; //I really like this font!
}
```

Now I want to replace this comment with a /* ... */ comment, so the output is like this:

```
body
{
    font-family: Georgia; /*I really like this font!*/
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks,

P.S. The complete CSSX file is read into one string variable.
P.P.S This q is answered. To fix the url('//server/etc.cssx') problem, use this:

```
$file =  preg_replace('~[^"\'\(]//([^\r\n]*)[^"\'\)]~', '/*$1*/', $file);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regexp should do the trick:

```
$str = preg_replace('_//(.*)$_m', '/*$1*/', $str);
```

This won't take into account quoted strings - if you're using something crazy like

```
background-image: url('//my-server/my.jpg');
```

then it's going to think that's a comment.
If this is a problem then you're better off writing a proper parser.

Comment: @Koning: they just specify the delimiter for the regular expression.  You can use many characters, and `preg_replace` will assume the first one is the delimiter you want to use.  The "standard" delimiter is `/`, but then you'd have to escape your `/`'s in the pattern.

Comment: Okay I understand. I thought only / was available as a delimiter.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the url(). Just use this: <code>$file =  preg_replace('~[^"\'\(]//([^\r\n]*)[^"\'\)]~', '/*$1*/', $file);</code>

Answer (score 3):

```
<? preg_replace('#//(.*)$#', '/*$1*/', $cssx); ?>
```

Comment: @Koning: I just can't compete with Greg's lightning fingers...  tnx

Answer (score 1):

Greg's expression has two problems: first, 'm' and '$' are superfluous, second it doesn't handle carriage returns correctly (in case your system uses them).

A better expression appears to be

```
 preg_replace('~//([^\r\n]*)~', '/*$1*/', $str);
```

Comment: Well, it's really important it'll work on OSX, Linux and Windows since I'll release the source.