# Replacing C++ single-line comments with C89 comments

Tags: c, language-agnostic, comments

What's a good way to replace single-line `// input number` comments with multi-line `/* input number */` comments?

I don't have any preference for the language used to accomplish the task; I was thinking of Perl or sed.  The source language will be C (ANSI X3.159-1989).

Simple scripts like

```
while(<>) {
  if (m#^(.*?)//#) {
    print $1;
  } else {
    print $_;
  }
}
```

would be fooled by strings containing `//` and are not OK.  Similarly, `//` inside a multi-line comment should be left alone.

Edit: Code can assume that there are no trigraphs.

---

This is the opposite of [replace C style comments by C++ style comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542006/341362).  It is similar to [Replacing // comments with /* comments */ in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1764311/341362) (though the accepted answer there cannot handle the special cases I mentioned and so is arguably wrong).

Comment: Need to check that // is not in any strings within the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boost::wave lexer's output to replace all the c++ style comments to C style comments. without getting bothered about the edge cases.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 #include <boost/wave/cpplexer/cpp_lex_token.hpp>
 #include <boost/wave/cpplexer/cpp_lex_iterator.hpp>

 typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_token<> token_type;
 typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_iterator<token_type> token_iterator;
 typedef token_type::position_type position_type;

 int main()
 {
       const char* infile = "infile.h";
     const char* outfile = "outfile.h";
       std::string instr;
       std::stringstream outstrm;
       std::string cmt_str;
       std::ifstream instream(infile);
       std::ofstream outstream(outfile);

       if(!instream.is_open()) {
               std::cerr << "Could not open file: "<< infile<<"\n";
           }
     if(!outstream.is_open()) {
         std::cerr << "Could not open file: "<< outfile<<"\n";
     }

           instream.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
           instr = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(instream.rdbuf()),
                                        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

           position_type pos(infile);
           token_iterator  it = token_iterator(instr.begin(), instr.end(), pos,
            boost::wave::language_support(boost::wave::support_cpp|boost::wave::support_option_long_long));
           token_iterator end = token_iterator();

           boost::wave::token_id id = *it;

      while(it!=end) {
         //here you check the c++ style comments 
         if(id == boost::wave:: T_CPPCOMMENT) {
            std::cout<<"Found CPP COMMENT";
            cmt_str = it->get_value();
            cmt_str[0] = '/';
            cmt_str[1] = '*';
            //since the last token is the new_line token so replace the new line
            cmt_str[cmt_str.size()-1] = '*';
            cmt_str.push_back('/');
            //and then append the newline at the end of the string 
            cmt_str.push_back('\n');
            outstrm<<cmt_str;
         }
         else {
           outstrm<<it->get_value(); 
         }
         ++it;
         id = *it;
     }
     outstream<<outstrm;

     return 0;
}
```

For further documentation please see:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/wave/index.html

Answer (score 3):

There are a *lot* of corner cases to consider.  Stray `//`s can appear in string literals, character constants (yes, really), and within `/* ... */` comments *and* `//` comments.  Line-splicing with trailing `\` characters can really mess things up -- and a `\` can be represented as the trigraph `??/`.  I seriously doubt that I've thought of all of them.

If you need a 100% reliable replacement, you're going to have to reproduce (or steal!) part of the preprocessor of a C compiler.

If you don't need 100% reliability, you might consider just doing a naive replacement, then comparing the input to the output and manually cleaning up any problems.  (For typically code, it's likely that there won't be any, but you'll need to check.)  The practicality of this approach depends in part on how much code you need to translate.

Most of the corner cases will result in code that won't compile:

```
printf("Hello // world\n");
```

-->

```
print("Hello /* world\n"); */
```

You might also consider whether this is really necessary.  Most C89/C90 compilers do support `//` comments, at least optionally.

Comment: The purpose is to make a piece of code match a project's style guide.  The compiler does, indeed, support single-line comments.  As for the amount of code, say 6-10 kLOC.

Comment: @Charles: Ok, that's a good reason.  It looks like all you need is a one-time conversion.  You'll probably spend less time manually fixing the corner cases than you would creating a 100% accurate tool.

Answer (score 1):

This won't cover 100% of corner cases, but it covers the ones you mentioned in your request.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
from sys import stdin, stdout

for line in stdin.readlines():
  line = line[:-1] # Trim the newline
  stripped = re.sub(r'[\'"].*[\'"]', '', line) # Ignore strings
  stripped = re.sub(r'/\*.*\*/', '', stripped) # Ignore multi-line comments
  m = re.match(r'.*?//(.*)', stripped) # Only match actual C++-style comments 
  if m:
    offset = len(m.group(1)) + 2
    content = line[:offset*-1] # Get the original line sans comment
    print '%s/* %s */' % (content, m.group(1)) # Combine the two with C-style comments
  else:
    print line
```